# Scheduling snowflake scripts from Tidal scheduler

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tidal-scheduler

How can we trigger the snowflake sql script through Tidal ?
How can we connect directly through tidal ?

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: You'll need to clarify this question. What is "snowflake" script? You tell the scheduler to run any commandline string you want, so it could be sqlcmd, powershell, whatever*. You set it to use any trigger you want that it supports, so a schedule, a file appearing in a directory, etc.

What does "connect directly through" mean?

*There is also an SQL adapter, but I haven't used it: https://www.tidalsoftware.com/integrations/data/microsoft-sql/

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports JDBC and ODBC drivers for connectivity.
You can download their latest version from the below links:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/
https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/index.html

In the next steps, we need to check if there is a way to integrate either of these drivers with the Tidal tool. I think it should be able to integrate them.

We can then use the below  Snowflake documentation to configure the JDBC driver for connectivity and usage:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html